# Effect of Base on E2 product

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, halides

[image]

One base is bulkier than the other, that's my observation. How does it affect the product? Could someone please give proper reasoning and the product? Thanks a lot.

P.S.
I guess both follow E2

Comment: With methoxide there is a reasonable chance of getting nucleophilic substitution as well as elimination generating a mixture of products.  With the much bulkier t-butoxide this is pretty well non-existent so you only get elimination.

Comment: It's also possible that the stronger base will abstract the most accessible proton, producing a less stable (kinetic) product.
The Zaitsev (thermodynamic) product comes from the least accessible proton in your case.

Comment: You might be under E1 conditions and not E2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under $E_2$ reaction conditions, the MeO$^-$ product will be

[image]

while the Me$_3$CO$^-$ product will be

[image].

This is due to the bulkiness of Me$_3$CO$^-$ being unable to reach the hydrogen at the substituted carbon so instead it goes to the primary position instead.

Comment: Do you have references that support this black/white distinction?